# Three dimension solid integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to find the volume of an integral bounded by z=4-x^2, x+y=2, and the coordinate planes. I know I just integrate one, but I can't set it up right. I know the limits for z are 0 and 4-x^2, and x is 0 and 2, but what would the limits for y be?

Answer (score 0):

To see this graph your functions in the $z=0$ plane to get

- $0=4-x^2$ which is just the vertical line $x = 4$
- $x+y=2$ and this is a line

So your y bounds go from $0$ to the line $y = \cdots$